# AngularJS tests - inject -> module -> inject

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test a service `documentViewer` that depends on some other service `authService`

```
  angular
    .module('someModule')
    .service('documentViewer', DocumentViewer);

  /* @ngInject */
  function DocumentViewer($q, authService) {
    // ...

    this.view = function(doc) {
      //...
    }
  }
```

This  is what my test looks like at the moment

```
it('test', inject(function($q) {
  var doc = {
    view: function() {
      return $q.resolve(0);
    }
  };

  var auth = {
    refreshProfileData: function() {
      return $q.resolve(0);
    },
  };

  var viewer = createViewer(auth);
}));

function createViewer(auth) {
  var viewer;

  module({
    authService: auth
  });
  inject(function(documentViewer) {
    viewer = documentViewer;
  });

  return viewer;
}
```

The problem is I need to call `inject` to grab a `$q`, then use it to create my mocks, register my mocks with `module`, and then call `inject` again to grab the unit under test.

This results in

> Error: Injector already created, can not register a module! in bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js (line 2278)

I've seen lots of answers here on SO saying you can't call `module` after `inject`, but they don't offer any alternative to a scenario like the above.

What's the correct approach here?

PS: I'd like to avoid using `beforeEach`, I want each test to be self-contained.

Comment: You can't have `module` after calling `inject`, that's what the error says. beforeEach is preferred way to do this. Otherwise a less readable way to do this is `it('...', () => { module(...); inject((...) => {...}) })`.

Comment: @estus What would such a solution look like? The problem is I need to grab a `$q` before calling `module`, and in order to do that I need `inject` (as far as I know, I'm still ramping up on angular/jasmine)

Comment: Something like that. It's not clear what `doc` is for, so it depends on the case if it becomes a showstopper or not. Any way, this pattern will be too inflexible most times, so it's likely an antipattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`module` is used to define which modules will be loaded with `inject` and cannot be called after `inject`, this is chicken-egg situation.

The object accepted by `module` is used to define mocked services [with `$provide.value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module):

> If an object literal is passed each key-value pair will be registered on the module via $provide.value, the key being the string name (or token) to associate with the value on the injector.

There can be no more than 1 function like `createViewer` that calls both `module` and `inject`. If this means that this kind of self-contained test is an antipattern, there is nothing that can be done about that. Angular testing works best with usual habits, including `beforeEach` and local variables.

In order to eliminate the dependency on `$q`, mocked service can be made a `factory`.

```
it('test', function () {
  var authFactory = function ($q) {
    return {
      refreshProfileData: function() {
        return $q.resolve(0);
      },
    };
  };

  // mocks defined first
  module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.factory('authService': authFactory);
  });

  var viewer;
  inject(function(documentViewer) {
    viewer = documentViewer;
  });
  // no module(...) is allowed after this point

  var $q;
  inject(function(_$q_) {
    $q = _$q_;
  });

  var doc = {
    view: function() {
      return $q.resolve(0);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Factories were the piece of the puzzle I was missing. I'll post my final solution later, for future reference.

Comment: As a site note: not only is setting up your mocks inside the test itself most definitely _not_ an anti pattern, it is also _required_ when different tests have different setups. Also, generalized setups often cause unnecessary code to run before each test; people end up stuffing everything they need inside a single `beforeEach`. There's a good reason why test frameworks like [`xunit`](https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons.html#note2) decided NOT to provide a `beforeEach`/`SetUp`  and `TearDown` mechanisms. See [this](http://jamesnewkirk.typepad.com/posts/2007/09/why-you-should-.html).

Comment: @dcastro We're talking about Angular testing, and it's an antipattern there. Angular is opinionated, so is angular-mocks. It works best with stuff like `beforeEach(module(...))`. The problem is not self-contained test (I don't think that xunit approach has a real reason, it's a matter of taste) per se but the way it is DRYed up with createViewer helper. If you will try to reimplement angular-mocks functionality by yourself for code above, you will run into the same chicken-egg situation. A pattern just doesn't work for Angular DI. I updated the answer with full sequence for self-contained test